# Google Play console displaying Release not live

Tags: android, google-play-console, release-management

Usually the when the application gets released in the Internal Channel, the build will get reflected instantly. Within a minute.

But strangely the build is not reflected even after a day. I am using the latest new Google console which displays the status as, ('Release not live' and not 'Being Reviewed')

[image]

Can you help to understand the behavior or the cases which might cause this

Comment: Could the version code be overshadowed by another internal release?

Comment: did you get any solution for this

Comment: No Solution found but there is a workaround.  Sometimes the status displays 'Release not live' sometimes the status displays like 'Available to all testers' but when the testers clicks on the download link, the Google Play displays 'Item not found' or keeps on loading.  So the workaround is to release another build (with a new version code) to the internal channel and it gets reflected and tester can able to download it

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem. Created a open beta Release for a build (there is no active production release at all!), Google approved it and now it's showing "Release not live". I can't understand why this happens and I think it is a bug on Googles side. I'll also submit a new build, but this is really annoying because Google has to review it again and that will take some time again.

Comment: seems to fix itself after in half an hour or or.. was getting similar thing when submitting build to "Open testing"-track which was paused and then resumed..

Answer (score 26):

This was happening to me when published an open beta version, it was the first release so in my case it was not a superseded version problem. I fixed it by completing the "Feedback URL or email address" field in the Open testing > Testers (Tab).

After doing that the status changed from "Release not live" to "Available to unlimited testers" with the green icon.

I've found it by pure luck since Play Console does not indicate where is the problem.

Answer (score 5):

This usually happens when you have a production bundle/apk with a version code greater than the Internal Track's bundle/apk version code.
Check if that's the case.

Comment: No this was not my case. Every release has a new version code. So the internal track release has greater version code than the production version. Not sure if this is bug in new Google Play console or any new policy been announced

Comment: This is exactly what happened with me, thanks man.

Answer (score 3):

I had another problem, so I summarize the both fixes.

### 1. Missing feedback url

Under `Testing>Open testing>Testers` fill the following

[image]

### 2. Bundle/apk version

Your bundle/apkversion code may be greater than the Internal Track's bundle/apk version code.

If it's your case, you'll have to publish a newer version.

### 3. Stuck on Publishing overview

If the publishing overview is set to `Managed publishing on` it wont be released neither.

1. Go under `Publishing overview`
2. Publish the content
   If you do not have any version live now & this was the reason why you were using the Managed publishing
3. Change `managed publishing` to `off` (top right)
4. Go under `>Setup>Advanced Settings`
5. Select `Unpublished`
6. **Warning:** You can download an open testing version **only** if the app is published
   [image]

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

This can also be because you have previously paused the track.

The track needs to be resumed.

Hope this helps someone as I have stumbled upon this myself and spent some time until I noticed the track was paused (I forgot about it)

Comment: Thank you! I don't remember when I paused the track, but your answer is really help me.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same thing. For me I had to complete the "Feedback URL or email address" field as stated above. Also in addition to that I had to go to App content and complete the Privacy Policy step. When I had declared that my app complied with Google Play Policies the status changed from "Release not live" to "Available to unlimited testers". Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't have testing at all and released straight through `Production` menu.

I had `versionName "1.00"` with `versionCode 1`. Since it's the first submission, it would take few days before it gets approved and while awaiting for approval, I added a functionality in my app.

I uploaded a new build with `versionName "1.00"` with `versionCode 2`.

I turned off `Managed Publishing` and waited for approval. Few days passed and both builds went `Superseded` or `Release not live`.

TLDR; I turned `Managed Publishing` to on again and my second build was successfully published!

Answer (score 0):

Click on Resume Track in: Open testing(Message in the top)
[image]