# Google Play 'Open Testing' (= Early Access): 'Release not live' error message

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-play, google-play-console

I want to release my app in Open Testing/Early Access.

I have the message 'Release not live' (indeed my app is not available on the store).

I don't understand why I have got this message and how to solve it.

Any idea?

Thanks !

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**ANSWER TO MY QUESTION**

After 1 hour, finally switched to 'Available to unlimited testers' and appeared on the store. Perhaps linked to the fact that I finally added a contact email in the 'testers' tab.

Comment: I uploaded the apk at 09:55 but until 11:35 am, the application status is still not live release, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73714579/11135174), the following may help

I had another problem, so I summarize the both fixes.

### 1. Missing feedback url

Under `Testing>Open testing>Testers` fill the following

[image]

### 2. Bundle/apk version

Your bundle/apkversion code may be greater than the Internal Track's bundle/apk version code.

If it's your case, you'll have to publish a newer version.

### 3. Stuck on Publishing overview

If the publishing overview is set to `Managed publishing on` it wont be released neither.

1. Go under `Publishing overview`
2. Publish the content
   If you do not have any version live now & this was the reason why you were using the Managed publishing
3. Change `managed publishing` to `off` (top right)
4. Go under `>Setup>Advanced Settings`
5. Select `Unpublished`
6. **Warning:** You can download an open testing version **only** if the app is published
   [image]

Cheers