# How can I try my new app version from the Google Play store?

Tags: android, google-play

My app in the Google Play store has a notice under "Policy status": *"App must target Android 13 (API level 33) or higher."* That is the overall problem I'm trying to solve.  The problem I describe below is that I uploaded a new version to the app store, but I can't seem to download it for testing.

I made a new version of the code, targetSdkVersion 33.  I uploaded it as version 4.0.15 (a.k.a. versionCode 28).

I also changed to using [App bundles](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle) (instead of an "APK"), because that's what it seemed like Google wanted.  A snapshot of my "App bundle explorer":

[image]

I wanted to try my app on my phone, so I set it to the "Open testing" track.  However, it says "No app bundles have been added." A snapshot of my "Open testing" / "Release details" (notice the "4.0.15" at the top):

[image]

There is no "Pre-launch report", I can't download it on my device (I'm in the "beta tester" track for the app.)

It's as if there's nothing uploaded, but I definitely uploaded this bundle:

```
$ ls -l app/release/app-release.aab 
-rw-r--r--  1 foo  staff  2932746 Sep 11 08:48 app/release/app-release.aab
```

and the "App bundle explorer" shows a bundle that's 2.45M:

[image]

When I go to the "App bundle explorer" / "Downloads" tab, it says I have to publish it to a track:

[image]

But "Open testing" / "Downloads" says the release is 4.0.15?  Snapshot:

[image]

So what's happening?  How do I download and test my version 4.0.15?

By the way, I tried clearing the "Play store" cache on my phone (and uninstalling and re-installing the app), as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58443639), and that did not help.  When I re-download the app, its about page says 4.0.14.

**EDIT**: When I promoted to production I had to add a bundle that was 4.0.15 from "the library", so that's why it was saying no bundles were included.

Comment: Did you try to [resume](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76885677/2779074) the track ?

Comment: Thanks. It does not appear paused. In "Open testing" there is a button "Pause track" on the right. If I click it, it asks, "Pause testing track?" So, given there's a pause, and no "resume", I assume it's not paused.

Comment: It does say "Inactive" for the "Release status" in the "App bundle explorer" (see snapshot above). I assume that's because it hasn't been fully released to production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From `Google Play Console` goto `App Bundle explorer`**

[image]

**then choose the build you want (click on the blue arrow all the way to the right)**

[image: choose the build]

**Then goto `downloads` tab and chose `Signed universal APK`, download the file to your phone and install it**

[image]

Comment: This worked, thanks. Two notes: 1) "click on the blue arrow" was really helpful", since I had to scroll right to see it, 2) I downloaded straight onto my phone, and had to change some settings to get it installed.